# What is the best eTPU IDE for engine control?

Tags: windows-10

I am a newbie in eTPU application development and I suffer to begin with the correct and the best IDE to work on both NXP and ST microelectronics target platforms. As I have searched on web, there are some popular IDE and tools as below;

- Freescale's CodeWarrior for ETPU IDE: Build, debug, simulate NXP targets
- Lauterbach Debug & Trace: Debug and trace data on NXP targets (MPC55xx and Coldfire)
- ByteCraft ETPU_C Compiler: Build ETPU_C code for NXP targets (Coldfire, PowerPC)
- Ashware eTPU2+ development tool: Build, debug, simulate, viw logic analyzer for NXP targets (MPC55xx, MPC56xx, MPC57xx, MCF52xx) and STMicroelectronics SPC563Mxx micro family.

I want to choose the best and user-friendly integrated solutions both work on NXP and ST target platforms. According to my search, Ashware eTPU2+ development tool seems the best IDE for building, debugging, simulating and viewing sketches of GPIO both on NXP and ST target platforms. Can anyone help me to guide about this issue?

Thanks in advance.
Turgay Kale